# Creating a generic function with no autowiring

Tags: java, generics

I have the following function:

```
private Object primaryObjects (AccountDTO accountDTO, String primaryEnum) {

  if (primaryEnum.equals(EmailAddressType.PRIMARY.toString())) {
     return accountDTO.getContactDetails()
        .getEmailAddressesDTO()
        .stream()
        .filter(emailAddressDTO -> emailAddressDTO.getType().equals(EmailAddressType.PRIMARY))
        .findFirst()
        .orElseThrow(() -> new EmailAddressNotFoundRuntimeException(accountDTO.getAccountId()));
  } else if (primaryEnum.equals(AddressType.PRIMARY.toString())){
     return accountDTO.getContactDetails()
        .getAddressesDTO()
        .stream()
        .filter(addressDTO -> addressDTO.getType().equals(AddressType.PRIMARY))
        .findFirst()
        .orElseThrow(() -> new HomeAddressNotFoundRuntimeException(accountDTO.getAccountId()));
  } else {
     return null;
  }

}
```

I am thinking of turning this into a generic method. Instead of passing a `String` as an argument, I'm thinking of passing a generic type (preferably the enum type) and based on the enum type, the method will return the respective object. For example, if we call `primaryObjects(accountDTO, EmailAddressEnum.PRIMARY)` the method should return an object of type EmailAddress..

I've tried created the following:

```
private <T> primaryObjects (AccountDTO accountDTO, T primaryEnum) {

  if (primaryEnum.equals(EmailAddressType.PRIMARY.toString())) {
     return accountDTO.getContactDetails()
        .getEmailAddressesDTO()
        .stream()
        .filter(emailAddressDTO -> emailAddressDTO.getType().equals(primaryEnum.PRIMARY))
        .findFirst()
        .orElseThrow(() -> new EmailAddressNotFoundRuntimeException(accountDTO.getAccountId()));
  } else if (primaryEnum.equals(AddressType.PRIMARY.toString())){
     return accountDTO.getContactDetails()
        .getAddressesDTO()
        .stream()
        .filter(addressDTO -> addressDTO.getType().equals(primaryEnum.PRIMARY))
        .findFirst()
        .orElseThrow(() -> new HomeAddressNotFoundRuntimeException(accountDTO.getAccountId()));
  } else {
     return null;
  }
}
```

But I get the following sytax errors: 
`Could not autowire. No beans of type 'T' found`.
`Could not autowire. No beans of type 'AccountDTO' found`.
`Could not return a value from a method with void return type.`

I'm not sure why im getting these autowiring errors (I'm using Spring Boot) and not sure why I'm getting the void return type error since the return type of the method is a generic T.

Comment: You have not specified the return type. `<T>` just makes sure that your method recognizes `T`. Change your method signature to `private <T> T primaryObjects` to remove compilation error.

Comment: 1) have you created bean of **AccountDto** yet?
2) From your first code only `.filter(emailAddressDTO -> emailAddressDTO.getType().equals(primaryEnum.PRIMARY))` is variying... So Instead of using generics, Passing **Predicate at run-time** will do your job